# Why does my range slider not work on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I have a problem with my webpage. I am trying to do a sidenav for layers on a map. It has to be able to move different layers (kind of like photoshop does), and set the opacity of a layer with a slider. It works fine on a desktop, but it doesn't on a touch screen. If I comment out the line that makes the list sortable the slider works on mobile, however I need it to be able to do both.

```
//makes html list of the current layers
function makeList()
{
    layersToArray();
    // Make a container element for the list
    var listContainer = document.createElement("div");
    // Add it to the page
    document.getElementById("layerStackSideNav").appendChild(listContainer);
    // Make the list
    var listElement = document.createElement("ul");
    listElement.setAttribute("id","sortable");
    // Add it to the page
    listContainer.appendChild(listElement);
    var numberOfListItems = layerNames.length;

    // Set up a loop that goes through the items in listItems one at a time
    for (var i = numberOfListItems-1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        // create an item for each one
        var listItem = document.createElement("li");
        // Add the item text
        listItem.innerHTML = layerNames[i];
        // Add listItem to the listElement
        listElement.appendChild(listItem);
        //Make opacity slider
        var sliderContainer = document.createElement("div");
        sliderContainer.setAttribute("class","sliderContainer");
        listItem.appendChild(sliderContainer);
        var opacitySlider = document.createElement("input");
        opacitySlider.setAttribute("id", layerNames[i]);
        opacitySlider.setAttribute("class", "slider");
        opacitySlider.setAttribute("type", "range");
        opacitySlider.setAttribute("min", "0");
        opacitySlider.setAttribute("max", "1");
        opacitySlider.setAttribute("step", "0.1");
        opacitySlider.setAttribute("value", "1");
        opacitySlider.setAttribute("oninput",
           "findLayerByName(\""+layerNames[i]+"\").setOpacity(this.value)");
        sliderContainer.appendChild(opacitySlider);
    }
}
```

Comment: which slider library/plugin are you using?

Comment: This is the default html5 range slider, no additional plugins are used to alter the way it works. Jquerry is used on the site in other parts, but not the slider itself.